# How to crawl updated webpage by scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I'm using scrapy to get data from a website.[The website](https://gold.jgi.doe.gov/projects) But there is a problem that I don't know how to get the increment data after the website has been updated in server or how to know the website has been updated? 
The table in webpage is what I want to crawl, like this:
[image]
Just as you can see, there is a column named "Add Date". So when the data has been updated,  I just want to get the data that has been added lately. And there is a problem that after updated the url of website won't have any changes. It's still `https://gold.jgi.doe.gov/projects`.

I've read this Q&A [Strategy for how to crawl/index frequently updated webpages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331738/strategy-for-how-to-crawl-index-frequently-updated-webpages). I understand a little bit of the theory. But I still don't know how to implement this when using scrapy, can anybody give an example or some detailed information?

Comment: Exactly what did you try so far ? Can you share some code ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to deal with this, so I'm asking for an example.

Comment: follow the [tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)

Comment: I do know how to write a spider to get data from a website, but I don't know how to get the data added recently after it has been updated.

Comment: @Coding_Rabbit I guess you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331738/strategy-for-how-to-crawl-index-frequently-updated-webpages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strategy for how to crawl/index frequently updated webpages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331738/strategy-for-how-to-crawl-index-frequently-updated-webpages)